# run bash script with suid set on file

Tags: bash, suid

I wrote a small bash script to test suid permission

```
$ cat phone.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "abc" >> out.txt

$ ls -l out.txt phone.sh
-rw-r--r-- root wzj      ...         out.txt
-rwsr-xr-x root wzj      ...         phone.sh

$ ./phone.sh
./phone.sh: 2: cannot create out.txt: Permission denied
```

why? I thought I already set the suid permission , so i can run the phone.sh with root privilege to modify the out.txt file , but i just failed. Can anybody tell me where i did wrong please?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/397612/929437 for explanation why `suid`ing scripts is a bad idea and how can you get around it

Comment: aland: thank you very much, i think i just doing things in a wrong way , i'm really new to bash script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most *nix OSes don't allow scripts to utilize SUID. Check out [Vidar's blog entry](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=30) on the subject. Perl scripts can use SUID, but as Vidar explains, it's due to how Perl is implemented. It appears Bash scripts simply won't run with SUID. Sorry I don't have a more useful answer for you, it looks like this is just "how things are".

Comment: Fls'Zen: Thank you for your article, I'm gonna read it tomorrow,it's 2:30am in japan now ^^